# ioBroker on Win10

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10, nvm

all!

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing? I try to install ioBroker on a Win10 server. I'll append a (kind of) log from the PowerShell session below.

Additional: There is a Visual Studio 2019 Community and a Visual Studio Code installed. I have not much experience with the Windows Build Tools (using VB.Net and C# until now), but it seems to me as if they are installed. I have installed Node.JS (including NPM) and NVM, using Node.JS 16.13.0.

I get no errors installing ioBroker, but no function either. It seems to me as if at least something is installed, getting all the subdirs below /iobroker, esp. the /iobroker/node_modules/iobroker subdir. But there is no service to start with "net start iobroker".

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> nvm -v
Running version 1.1.8.
[ . . . ]

PS C:\Windows\system32> nvm list available

|   CURRENT    |     LTS      |  OLD STABLE  | OLD UNSTABLE |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|    17.0.1    |   16.13.0    |   0.12.18    |   0.11.16    |
|    17.0.0    |   14.18.1    |   0.12.17    |   0.11.15    |
[ . . . ]

PS C:\Windows\system32> nvm list
  * 16.13.0 (Currently using 64-bit executable)

PS C:\Windows\system32> node -v
v16.13.0

PS C:\Windows\system32> npm -v
8.1.0

PS C:\Windows\system32> md \iobroker

PS C:\Windows\system32> cd \iobroker

PS C:\iobroker> npm install iobroker

added 60 packages, and audited 61 packages in 4s

6 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
npm notice
npm notice New patch version of npm available! 8.1.0 -> 8.1.2
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.1.2
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@8.1.2 to update!
npm notice

PS C:\iobroker> npm install --production

up to date, audited 61 packages in 676ms

6 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

PS C:\iobroker> dir -n

node_modules
package-lock.json
package.json

PS C:\iobroker> dir .\node_modules\ -n

.bin
ansi-regex
call-bind
[ . . . ]
yargs
yargs-parser
.package-lock.json

PS C:\iobroker> dir .\node_modules\iobroker\ -n

install
lib
.gitattributes
CHANGELOG_FIXER_LINUX.md
CHANGELOG_INSTALLER_LINUX.md
fix_installation.sh
LICENSE
package.json
README.md
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need npm6 to follow those installation notes. Use

```
npm i -g npm@6
```

to downgrade.

Comment: Uhoh... Now I am not able to call NPM any more:
PS C:\Users\mritt> npm -v
npm : Die Datei "C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.ps1" kann nicht geladen werden. Die Datei "C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.ps1" ist nicht digital signiert. Sie können dieses Skript im aktuellen System nicht ausführen. [ . . . ] --> Something about "not signed" error.

Comment: ok, with "set-executionpolicy -executionpolicy remotesigned -scope currentuser" I got "npm -v" working again, displaying "6.14.15" as result. Phew...

Comment: And... Tadaaa! It worked! Thanks, mate!

Comment: I wonder if there's a signature for npm8